# How to prevent user (having db_datawriter) from being able to connect via management studio?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2019

I have a windows sql user that is assigned db_datawriter role on a db.

Presently the user can connect to the database via management studio and make changes to the data in the database.

Also, he can use a windows forms application that connects to the database (using connection string) using his windows credentials and modifies the data.

I want to prevent this user from being able to connect via management studio. But continue to allow him to modify the data via the windows forms application.

Comment: There isn't a way. They could connect using any client tool. Powershell, VBA, `SQLCMD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly a security question, but also a design question, so I'll give you an answer on both fronts.

**Using Interfaces**

`db_datawriter` is almost always too permissive. Rarely does an application actually need the permission to write to every table in an ad-hoc manner. By way of analogy, think about the classes you create when you build an application. Do they look like this?

```cs
class MyClass
{
   public int someIntIneedForAnInternalAlgorithm;
   public string someStringThatCanOnlyChangeInternally;
   public ISomeInterface SomeInterfaceMyImplementationNeeds;
   // ...
}
```

Probably not. They should look more like this:

```cs
class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(ISomeInterface injectedInterface) { // ...
   private int someIntIneedForAnInternalAlgorithm;
   public string SomeStringThatCanOnlyChangeInternally { get; private set; }
   private readonly ISomeInterface theInterfaceIneeded;
   // ...
```

In other words, some of the internal state of the class is typically private. You interact with it through some controlled public interface.

A database is not different. You can think of the tables as the "internal state". The application doesn't need direct access to all of that, it should access it through an interface. The interface could be made up of views, functions, or stored procedures. You then grant access only to the objects in the "public interface", according to the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

You might still want to allow users to read from the tables arbitrarily - for example, maybe you trust them enough to let them write their own queries for reporting purposes. But you don't let them write arbitrarily to the tables.

This isn't a complete solution: if your users are able to connect using their own credentials, they can still manipulate the database directly through that interface. But at least they don't have ad-hoc permission to interact with the tables arbitrarily.

**Application Credentials**

What if this isn't enough? What if you want to ensure that the only way to interact with the database is through the application? Well, then you create a login *for the application*. The application connects as itself, on behalf of the user, instead of forwarding the user's credentials.

There are, of course, downsides to this approach. For one, it means that you have lost information about who is doing what. Previously if you had something like a `modified_by` column on a table, you could populate that column with absolute confidence using something like the `original_login()` function. But now the `original_login()` function will return the application login. So you have to provide the user information some other way, for example as parameter data to your stored procedures, or by passing it as [session context](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4094/phase-out-contextinfo-in-sql-server-2016-with-sessioncontext/).

Another downside is that you might have been using active directory security groups to provide more granular permission. For example, you might have created a login for `MyCompany\Sales Department`, and granted that group special permissions to be able to interact with sales data. But now the application is doing the logging in for everyone, so it needs the ability to do everything.

**Can I Have My Cake and Eat it Too?**

"OK", I hear you say, "I understand these ideas, but here's the thing. I want to control access according the application's identity, but I also want to control access according to the user's identity."

Prima facie, the answer to this seems to be "tough luck", right? Like, isn't that a contradiction? You are either logging in as the user, or the application. It can't be both. So you can't control permissions according to both.

But that answer does make an assumption: It assumes that the only way to get identity information is via the transport credentials (ie, the login). But that's not entirely true. There are two ways to escape this apparent contradiction:

1. Log in using the application identity, pass the user identity as data, and resolve additional permissions with logic inside the database making use of the user identity data, or...
2. Log in using the user's credentials, use normal SQL Server roles and permissions to provide access to the interface, but make sure that the login is coming from the application.

How do you do each of these? Which is easier to implement? Which is more secure?

Unfortunately the answer to the second question is different from the answer to the third.

Let's look at the first way. Suppose you pass the users' active directory username to the database when you access it. Can you check the security groups of that user? Sure. You can use the `xp_logininfo` procedure to get the "permisison paths" for some given user name. But I'm not even going to start going into the details of how you would have to write your database interface in order to make use of this. In involves making use of `execute as`, it involves manually resolving sql permissions via data... it's just a hell of a lot of work.

So, forget that, what about the second way? Well, that's much easier. You come up with some secret key. You give the secret key to the application. The application still forwards user credentials to log in, but when someone tries to use one of the objects in your database interface, you check that the secret key is correct. You can again use `session_context` for this.

Is this "a bit of a kludge"? Maybe. But hey, we're trying to control permissions two different ways simultaneously. Absolute elegance is not something we're likely to achieve.

Using this approach in a stored procedure

```
create or alter procedure p as begin
   set nocount on;
   if (isnull(session_context(N'applicationKey'), '') != 'my secret value') 
      throw 50001, 'Access to this database is only allowed through MyApplication', 1;
   /*
   do work here
   */
end
```

Using it in a view...

```
create view v as 
   select *
   from   sys.objects
   where  session_context(N'applicationKey') = 'my secret value'
```

**Quick, Dirty, Potentially Dangerous Hack if you want Minimal Code Changes**

There is another way, but it has a lot of issues and I wouldn't really recommend it: A logon trigger. To use it, you would add the application name to your connection string, and make sure you set an initial catalog as well

```
"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Application Name=myappname; Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Then check the application name value of the connection string in the login trigger.  You also want to make sure you don't prevent other potentially valid logins from connecting though, so check the database name too, as well as checking that the user logging in is a member of the group you want to restrict. In this example I've used the `db_datareader` role, but I would suggest making a role specific to your application:

```
CREATE TRIGGER application_check
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
for logon
AS
begin
   if (
         is_member(original_login(), 'db_datareader')
         and db_name() = 'mydatabase' 
         and app_name() != 'myappname'
   ) rollback;
end
```

Comment: In the c# winforms app, I can use the `SELECT IS_MEMBER('DB_DATAWRITER')` to test for permissions.

Comment: @variable How would you use that?

Comment: I write the above query via ADO.NET so that the windows user that opens the windows forms app gets authenticated against the DB_DATAWRITER role in the database.

Comment: @variable sure, what I mean is: how does that help you? You want to avoid letting the users write data arbitrarily. But if they are a member of `db_datawriter` then they can write arbitrarily, which is what you want to prevent.

Comment: I want to use the above approach to authenticate the windwos user into my windows forms app - so that all data modifications via the app happen in the context of the windows user. This is OK. What I want to ask is - at the same time how do I prevent that user from using management studio to access/mmodify the database data?

Comment: @variable I know. But you can't give someone `db_datawriter` permission, and then also prevent them from having `db_datawriter` permission, right? That's obviously a contradiction. What I've given you in my *extensive* answer is a way to achieve what you want to achieve, but without giving the users `db_datawriter` membership in the first place. Why are you insistent on using `db_datawriter`?

Comment: The problem with using the application credentials is that - it will have to be hardcoded into the win forms code. And everytime the application credential password changes we will have to re-deploy the app to every user.

Comment: There are solutions to problems like that (such as KeyVault if you're on azure). But I also gave you another solution in my answer: keep authenticating with user credentials, only grant permissions to an explicit interface made of stored procedures and views instead of granting `db_datawriter` permission, and use `context_info` with some kind of secret to check that the login is coming from your application.

Comment: Your suggestion of stored procedures makes absolute sense. Thank you.

Comment: @variable Just in case you want a quick, dirty hack that will work with minimal code changes - at least temporarily - I have added one final option to my answer.